# How to handle specific table elements on a dynamically generated table in REACT JS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am new on React and I have the following use case:
I have a JSON that I mapped out in a dynamically generated table I had no problem with that but now I want a popup to show up below the row in the table whenever I hover over a that row. This popup has to show additional information about the summarized info in the row.

I generated to table in a component as follow:

```
function ScheduleComponent(props) {

// Required hooks


    useEffect(() => {
        setSchedule(props.schedule);
    }, [props.schedule]);

    const handleMouseOver = () => {
        // I dont know what to do here
    };

    const handleMouseOut = () => {
        //neither here 
    };


    const showAppointments = schedule.map((appointment, i) => {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{appointment.hourOfService}</td>
                {
                    appointment.appointmentDto != null ?
                        <div>
                        <td onMouseOver={handleMouseOver} onMouseOut={handleMouseOut} >{appointment.appointmentDto.name}</td> 
                        </div> :
                        <td>No hay citas programadas</td>
                }                
            </tr>
        );
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th > Hora </th>
                            <th > Descripcion </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {showAppointments}                        
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default ScheduleComponent;
```

I get the JSON via props but this is not the problem.
I automatically generate the table with the funtion **showAppointments**

The result in HTML is:

[image]

Whenever I hover over an appointment I want to show additional info in a popup but just for that appointment row and set that popup below the row element. I had some ideas but whenever I hover over one name, a popup shows for every name ( the 4 names in this case, i mean 4 popups).
Hence, is there a way to generate the table automatically and in some way condition the appearance of a popup just for one row.
Thanks in advance!!! I really appreciate your time folks!

Answer (score 0):

As a easiest solution: You may pass the object or its ID to handleMouseOver function like this:

```js
    const showAppointments = schedule.map((appointment, i) => {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{appointment.hourOfService}</td>
                {
                    appointment.appointmentDto != null ?
                        <div>
                        <td onMouseOver={() => { handleMouseOver(appointment) }} onMouseOut={handleMouseOut} >{appointment.appointmentDto.name}</td> 
                        </div> :
                        <td>No hay citas programadas</td>
                }                
            </tr>
        );
    });
```

Then you have to change the `handleMouseOver` function to handle 1 specific record passed as parameter.

Comment: Thanks you gave me some insights.  I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer:

```
    const handleMouseOver = (i) => {
    setShowElement(i);
};

const handleMouseOut = () => {
    setShowElement(-1);
};


const showAppointments = schedule.map((appointment, i) => {
    return (           
        <tr>
            <td>{appointment.hourOfService}</td>
            {
                appointment.appointmentDto != null ?
                    <div onMouseOver={() => { handleMouseOver(i) }} onMouseOut={handleMouseOut} >
                        <td >{appointment.appointmentDto.name}</td>
                        {showElement === i && <div><ul>
                            <li>Telefono: {appointment.appointmentDto.phone}</li>
                            <li>Descripcion: {appointment.appointmentDto.description}</li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>}
                    </div> :
                    <td>No hay citas programadas</td>
            }

        </tr>


    );
});
```

I added

```
{showElement === i && <div><ul><li>Telefono: {appointment.appointmentDto.phone}</li><li>Descripcion: {appointment.appointmentDto.description}</li></ul></div>}
```

once I passed the prop `i` via the eventHandler

Thanks for the guidance [Oleg Imanilov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2304204/oleg-imanilov)